# Checking if an element of an array is included in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have arrays:

```
a = [1,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3]
```

Is there any short way to check as follows?

```
a.include? b
```

It should return `true` as `3` is there.

We can do:

```
b.each do |bb|
 puts true if a.include? bb
end
```

but this is not a good way to iterate over a big array. Or:

```
c = [2,4]
a.include? b
```

should return `true` without iteration.

Comment: Your naming `include?` is highly misleading.

Answer (score 8):

You could intersect the arrays. If the intersection is non-empty, the arrays have common elements:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,4]

(a & b).any? # true
!(a & b).empty? # => true
```

This is quite efficient as it uses a temporary hash under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope you may be want something like `intersect` kind of thing used in `Set`

```
 require 'set'
 Set[1,3,4,5].intersect? Set[1,2,3] # => true
```

[Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-intersect-3F) it is

Answer (score 1):

If I subtract `b - a` and `a` has some elements that `b` has too, then the new array of `b - a` has a smaller number of elements, because `b - a` returns all elements, which `b` has but `a` has not. I can check the result against the original size.

```
a = [1,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3]
b.size > (b - a).size
# => true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array intersection:

```
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    b = [2,4]
    c = [5,6]
```

It gives following results:

```
   (a & b).any?
   # true
   (a & c).any?
   # false
```